# Simple shortcode to check if a user has commented on a certain post

Tags: posts, shortcode, comments

Hi all (mi first question on StackExchange, sorry in advance for my inability)
I want to make a shortcode to check if the current user has commented on a specific post.
I found this code as a starting point:

```
// function that runs when shortcode is called
function ccheck_shortcode( $post_id = false, $user_id = false ) { 
  
// Things that you want to do.
$args = array(
    'user_id' => get_current_user_ID(), // use user_id
    'post_id' => get_the_ID()
 );

$comment = get_comments($args);

if(!empty($comment)) echo 'You commented';

}
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('ccheck', 'ccheck_shortcode');
```

but i would like to specify the post id with a shortcode parameter, in order to use it everywhere,
( [ccheck postid=""] ) so i tried this:

```
// function that runs when shortcode is called
function ccheck_shortcode( $post_id = false, $user_id = false, $atts ) { 
  
// Things that you want to do.
$args = array(
    'user_id' => get_current_user_ID(), // use user_id
    'post_id' => get_the_ID($atts['postid'])
 );

$comment = get_comments($args);

if(!empty($comment)) echo 'You commented';

}
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('ccount', 'ccheck_shortcode');
```

Of course it doesn't work. Tips?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made 2 small errors.

First of all: Shortcode-Functions receive a maximum of 2 parameters: $attributes and $content.

`$attributes` is an array of all the attributes within the shortcode, like `[shortcode post_id=123]` the attribute `post_id` will end up in the $attributes array as `$attributes['post_id']`.

`$content` has the content *between* the opening and the closing shortcode tag, like in `[shortcode]Content in between[/shortcode]`, the text `Content in between` would end up in the `$content` parameter.

So, if you want to give the post_id to your shortcode function, you need to get it from the first parameter.

The second error is that the function `get_the_ID()` doesn't take any parameters, but returns the current post ID. So you don't need to call `get_the_ID( $post_id )`, you just use the `post_id` you put in the shortcode attributes directly.

I put in an check if the attribute `post_id` is set. If not, it takes the current Post ID. If it is set, it looks for the comments for the attribute `post_id`.

Lastly, be sure to always `return` the result of shortcodes, never `echo` directly. Because of the point within the Wordpress Code, at which shortcode functions are run, you could (and will) end up with errors or positions for your shortcode results that you not intended.

```
// function that runs when shortcode is called
function ccheck_shortcode( $attributes ) { 
   
    // Things that you want to do.
    $args = array(
        'user_id' => get_current_user_ID(), // use user_id
        'post_id' => get_the_ID()
    );
    if( isset( $attributes['post_id'] ) ){
         $args['post_id'] = absint($attributes['post_id']);
    } 

    $comment = get_comments($args);

    if(!empty($comment)){
      return 'You commented';
    }
    return "";
}
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('ccount', 'ccheck_shortcode');
```

Happy Coding!